# bash script se cierra sin mas en ejecucion larga

Tags: mysql, bash

Tengo un script que hasta la fecha funcionaba bastante bien.
Este hace varias consultas sencillas a mysql y después actúa sobre una tabla de varios millones de registros eliminando coincidencias con otra tabla.

El tema es que el último trabajo fue bastante mas pesado que los anteriores (calculé unas 18 horas) y el script salió sin más al finalizar/durante la consulta de eliminación de mysql aunque aparentemente la eliminacion recorrió todos los registros puesto que no he encontrado duplicados.
También es posible que ya se hubieran eliminado todos los duplicados cuando el script cascó, aún quedando registros por revisar.

Aquí el código donde sucedió la anomalía:

```
/bin/echo "Eliminando registros que ya tengo en DB generica....."
/usr/bin/mysql $SQL_ARGS_LOCAL "delete FROM tabla1 where bbdd_fid=$BBDD_FID_ADD and dato1 in (select dato1 from tabla2)"
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then         # Si me da error
/bin/echo "Ha ocurrido un error o no se ha completado la eliminacion de registros en la DB de tabla1 bbdd_fid $BBDD_FID_ADD ($NOMBRE_DB_ADD)"
fi
# De nuevo cuento los registros despues de la eliminacion
/bin/echo
/bin/echo -n "Registros en $NOMBRE_DB_ADD bbdd_fid $BBDD_FID_ADD despues de la eliminacion: "
```

La última linea del log muestra:

> Eliminando registros que ya tengo en DB generica.....

Después se quedó ejecutando `/usr/bin/mysql $SQL_ARGS_LOCAL "delete FROM tabla1 where .......` y después el script salió.

¿Es posible que al finalizar la consulta de eliminación no se puediera retomar el código y saliera anormalmente?

Tampoco he podido ver la hora de finalización o si ha soltado algún error en los logs del sistema.

Comment: ¿Puedes ejecutar de nuevo la consulta con un triple `verbose`y capturar `stderr`? Tal vez ahí puedas ver el error y si es necesario, edita tu pregunta y copia las partes más importantes de ese registro.

Comment: Hola @kk003 Ya he avisado al moderador para que elimine esta pregunta y tengas la otra. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias miquel, por desgracia creo que han borrado el mensaje equivocado. De momento puedo comentar asi que contestando a @toledano: No se como se hace este triple verbose que comentas (seguro que si googleo lo encuentro) pero intuyo que te refieres a mysql. La cuestion aqui es que al salir de la linea "delete from..." no regresa a la linea siguiente del script. Si estoy en lo cierto necesitaria ver un log de la ejecucion del script en si mismo, no de los resultados del mismo que ya adelanto que salio anormalmente. Se puede monitorizar bash cuando  ejecuta un script y ver su codigo de salida?.

Comment: @kk003 Se unieron ambas preguntas sobre tu pregunta original y ya podés editar y comentar sobre esta pregunta.

Comment: @kk003 Cómo comenta Mariano se han fusionado ambas preguntas y ya tienes control completo de esta. ¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 4):

Te puedo aconsejar durante procesos largos, o ejecuciones que tardarán horas, crear archivos de salida temporales. Esto lo puedes hacer con `tee`, redireccionando a un archivo:

`/usr/bin/mysql $SQL_ARGS_LOCAL "delete FROM tabla1 where bbdd_fid=$BBDD_FID_ADD and dato1 in (select dato1 from tabla2)" |tee Output1.txt`

Con esto, si falla la ejecución, podrás tener hasta qué parte del proceso se cumplió.

Para saber el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse un script, puedes hacerlo de dos maneras:

1. Ejecuta tu bash anteponiendo `time./s1.sh`
   donde `s1.sh` es tu programa.
2. O poner estas líneas al inicio y al final dentro tu script:

   `res1=$(date +%s.%N)` (inicio despues de /bin/bash)
   `res2=$(date +%s.%N)` (final)
   y por último la salida en segundos:

   ```
   printf "Mi programa tardo :    %.3F\n"  $(echo "$res2 - $res1"|bc )
   ```

Comment: Gracias, uso tee regularmente segun que trabajo realice. Lo de time me era desconocido, lo probare en cuanto pueda. Lo que propones en el punto 2 es lo que suelo hacer siempre que me interesa cuanto durara la tarea. En lo que se refiere al problema que planteo en mi pregunta en mi opinión la maquina se saturo de algún modo a raíz de la cola de consultas mysql, no solo por la consulta que muestro en si, también por peticiones web a la DB y seguramente numero de conexiones, etc. He hecho unos cuantos ajustes restringiendo consultas locales y servicios web innecesarios y la cosa ha mejorado.

Comment: La causa del problema fue que mientras el script se estaba ejecutando lo edite para hacer modificaciones menores. Cuando regreso de la consulta larga de mysql que muestro en la pregunta se ve que casco. Me he asegurado de que ese fue el problema, al menos con el tipo de código que ejecuto. Tenia entendido que en bash los scripts se cargan en memoria antes de ejecutarse y supuse que todo el proceso se trabajaba desde ahí ignorando (según mi erróneo pensamiento) posibles modificaciones en el soporte físico. Es algo que no suelo hacer, pero en un proceso tan largo ya se sabe.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la sensación de que tu problema está más relacionado con los timeouts de la conexión. Si estás ejecutando el programa desde una conexión SSH o TELNET, después de varias horas hay timeouts, incluso menos el algunos casos. Puede ser cosa del firewall, del server, incluso de la propia conexión o del cliente. Hay distintas formas de evitarlo. Con ssh sería editando el fichero /etc/ssh/sshd_config y añadiendo estas líneas:

> ClientAliveInterval 120
>   ClientAliveCountMax 720

Esto te permitirá extender tu conexión SSH a 24 horas
(120 segundos x 720 veces = 86400 segundos).

Sin embargo, la solución, en tu caso, creo que es evitar que el proceso se interrumpa.

Cuando se cierra la conexión, lo que hace en proceso init es matar al todos los subprocesos asociados a esa conexión.

La solución: utiliza el comando bash [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/nohup), que significa "No hang up" (No colgar). Le indica al script que ignore la [señal SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) recibida Haz lo siguiente:

```
nohup "nombre_del_script.sh"
```

Te dejará todo el output de pantalla en un fichero llamado nohup.out en el mismo directorio donde hayas ejecutado el comando.

Comment: Igual te interesa también usar el comando "nice" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix  para subirle la prioridad al proceso, ya que por defecto los procesos ejecutados bajo nohup tienen una prioridad de ejecución menor (es decir, tardan más).